# Shopify Public App INSTALL button redirect oddity

Tags: javascript, pug, shopify

This is an oddity that occurs after the Shop's admin user clicks the Install button

The user clicks the 'GET' button and the that works just fine.  The next page the user sees is the 'INSTALL' button page.

When the user clicks install a call is made back to my server, I do the request post and get back the applicable token.

Then a get to my server is made and I serve up a page, and that page is rendered **in the browser's *full* window**.  I would expect it to be in the iFrame of the `store's/admin/apps/_myapp_` page.

And if I close the page.  Then navigate to `store's/admin/apps/_myapp_` the page I host **is** now properly rendered as you would expect it, in the iFrame.

And tips / thoughts.  What is or isn't happening on that click from the 'INSTALL' button

But the way this is the page I sent to the resolution of he 'INSTALL'.  I believe I have the re-directs appropriately setup.  But maybe you will see something I'm not.  This is in Jade/Pug.

```
extends layout
block content
  script(src="/jquery/dist/jquery.js")
  script.
    function doThePost() {
      alert('hello world');
    }

  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  p
  p
  p
  input(type="text", id="shopUrl", name="shopUrl", value="#{shopUrl}", hidden="hidden")
  input(type="text", id="shop", name="shop", value="#{shop}", hidden="hidden")
  p
  button(onclick='doThePost()') v1Demo
  p
  p end

  script(type="text/javascript").
    var shpUrl = $('#shopUrl').val();
    var shp = $('#shop').val();
    // If the current window is the 'parent', change the URL by setting location.href
    if (window.top == window.self) {
      window.top.location.href = 'https://' + shpUrl + '/admin/oauth?shop=' + shp;
    // If the current window is the 'child', change the parent's URL with postMessage
    } else {
      message = JSON.stringify({
        message: "Shopify.API.remoteRedirect"
        , data: { location: window.location.origin + '/admin/oauth?shop=' + shp }
      });
      window.parent.postMessage(message, 'https://' + shpUrl);
    }
```